# Can we use least squares for the following problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, regression, least-squares, linear-regression

I have the following model of some data:
\begin{equation}
\mathbf{Y} = \mathbf{Ax} + \eta\left(Y,x\right)
\end{equation}
where, $\mathbf{Y} = \left[y_1 \ \ y_2 \ \ \cdots \ \ y_n\right]^T$ is the measured data. $\mathbf{x}$ is a vector of parameters to be estimated. $\eta$ is noise with mean zero and has some non-zero covariance. It is to be noted that $\eta$ is a function of the observed variables and parameters to be estimated. Can I use Least Squares method to obtain the estimates of $\mathbf{x}$? If not, why?. Assume that number of data points is much larger than the numbers of parameters to be estimated.

Comment: Is $\eta$ a (known?) deterministic function of $Y$ and $x$? Your description says $\eta$ is a random variable but your equation expresses that it *only* depends on deterministic variables. Maybe you meant $\eta(Y, x, \omega)$ where $\omega$ is a random variable with some (known?) mean and covariance?

Comment: If we assume $\eta_i$ is error in $y_i$, then $\eta_i$ has the following structure:
$\eta_i = a_1\nu_1 - a_2\nu_2+y_i\nu_3-y_j\nu_4+\nu_5+\nu_6$
where, $\nu\sim\mathcal{N}\left(0,1\right)$ and $a_i$ are deterministic.

Comment: I was not able to modify the previous comment. But $\eta_i$ is:
$\eta_i = a_1\nu_1-a_2\nu_2+(y_i - x_k)\nu_3 - (y_j - x_l)\nu_4+\nu_5+\nu_6$, where indices $I,j,k,l$ represent $I^{th},j^{th},\cdots$ variable.